# How to configure software using chef and vagrant after install recipe runs

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

Thanks for taking a look at this question. Any help is appreciated.
I am provisioning a virtual machine with a GUI using vagrant and chef.

Goal: to download IntelliJ IDE and then install it so that it is available to my user when I log in.

The cookbook `cookbook 'idea', '~> 0.4.0'`achieves the download but a user must manually complete the install on the guest.

I am having trouble with my custom recipe to complete the configuration with chef. As it is written, the recipe completes if I add it to the run list after the machine is provisioned but fails in the initial run because files are not yet installed.

I tried using the `only_if` method within the relevant blocks and on the entire recipe, but couldn't get it to work. I also messed with the `subscribe` method but couldn't get that to work either.

I'm sure this has an easy solution, but Googling and trial and error are not getting me any closer. I would appreciate any help to achieve the goal. Thanks!

**Current recipe**

```
# Configure IntelliJ Idea.
file '/opt/idea/idea.desktop' do
  content '[Desktop Entry]
      Name=IntelliJ IDEA
      Type=Application
      Exec=idea
      Terminal=false
      Icon=idea
      Comment=Integrated Development Environment
      NoDisplay=false
      Categories=Development;IDE;
      Name[en]=IntelliJ IDEA'
  mode '644'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
end

bash 'install idea desktop' do
  code <<-EOH
  cd /opt/idea
  sudo desktop-file-install idea.desktop
  EOH
end

file '/usr/share/pixmaps/idea.png' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
  content ::File.open('/opt/idea/bin/idea.png').read
  action :create
end

link '/usr/local/bin/idea' do
  to '/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh'
  link_type :symbolic
end
```

**Failed efforts:**
Wrapping the entire script

```
 # Configure IntelliJ Idea.
    execute 'configure idea' do
      only_if { ::File.exist?("/opt/idea") }
    continues...
    end
```

Using `only_if` in the blocks

```
file '/usr/share/pixmaps/idea.png' do
    action :create
    only_if { ::File.exist?('/opt/idea/bin/idea.png') }
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    content ::File.open('/opt/idea/bin/idea.png').read
  end

  link '/usr/local/bin/idea' do
    to '/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh'
    only_if { ::File.exist?('/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh') }
    link_type :symbolic
  end
```

Comment: Thank you @coderanger. Your solution worked as intended. I edited the two blocks that needed to be delayed until converge time and the machine provisioned as expected.
`...  content lazy { ::File.open('/opt/idea/bin/idea.png').read }` and `...to lazy { '/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is a lazy evaluated property:

```
content lazy { ::File.open('/opt/idea/bin/idea.png').read }
```

That will delay the file read until converge time instead of compile time.